# Password input field change from text to password on focus/type?

Tags: javascript, html, css, passwords

I have a sign up form where the titles of the inputs are in the text box, and when you click on the box, the text disappears, but on the password i want the preview text to remain as "password" and not "••••••••". BUT when the user clicks on the text box should clear out the text, and their entered text should apear as "•••••••".

This is the code for the buttons:

```
<form method="post" action="register_process.php">
    <input type="text" class="button" value="USERNAME" onclick="this.value='';this.onclick='test';this.style.color='#000';" onfocus="if (this.value == 'USERNAME') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'USERNAME';}" name="username"  />
    <input type="text" class="button" value="EMAIL" onclick="this.value='';this.onclick='test';this.style.color='#000';" onfocus="if (this.value == 'EMAIL') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'EMAIL';}" name="email"  />
    <input type="text" class="button" value="PASSWORD" onclick="this.value='';this.onclick='test';this.style.color='#000';" onfocus="if (this.value == 'PASSWORD') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'PASSWORD';}" name="password"  />
    <input type="text" class="button" value="PASSWORD CONFIRM" onclick="this.value='';this.onclick='test';this.style.color='#000';" onfocus="if (this.value == 'PASSWORD CONFIRM') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'PASSWORD CONFIRM';}" name="password_confirm"  />    <br/>
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="JOIN!" name="join!"  />
</form>
```

All else works fine but I would like the users passwords not to show up. Also for now I have left the password fields as text.

To see it action see here: http://jsfiddle.net/e458S/

Thanks.

Comment: Are you against using libraries?

Comment: The HTML5 attribute `placeholder` would make your life much easier. Browser support is coming around (IE 10, FF, Chrome, Safari)

Comment: @TimMedora For the time being what should I use?

Comment: @Daedalus What is that/what does it do?

Comment: You definitely want to keep using `input type=password`; the browser often has special security rules around such inputs (e.g. preventing copying). You could add the `placeholder` attribute for newer browsers; older browsers won't see anything (so you may want to add a label next to the input).

Comment: @HarrisonHoward I was going to suggest a library for solving this, but there doesn't appear to be a real fix available, so instead I upvoted Vahe's answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use javascript `setAttribute`

```
<form method="post" action="register_process.php">
   <input type="text" class="button" value="USERNAME" onclick="this.value='';this.onclick='test';this.style.color='#000';" onfocus="if (this.value == 'USERNAME') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'USERNAME';}" name="username"  />
   <input type="text" class="button" value="EMAIL" onclick="this.value='';this.onclick='test';this.style.color='#000';" onfocus="if (this.value == 'EMAIL') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'EMAIL';}" name="email"  />
   <input type="text" class="button" value="PASSWORD" onclick="this.value='';this.onclick='test';this.style.color='#000'; setAttribute('type', 'password');" onfocus="if (this.value == 'PASSWORD') {this.value = ''; setAttribute('type', 'password');}"   onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'PASSWORD';setAttribute('type', 'text');}" name="password"  />
   <input type="text" class="button" value="PASSWORD CONFIRM" onclick="this.value='';this.onclick='test';this.style.color='#000'; setAttribute('type', 'password');" onfocus="if (this.value == 'PASSWORD CONFIRM') {this.value = ''; setAttribute('type', 'password');}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'PASSWORD CONFIRM'; setAttribute('type', 'text');}" name="password_confirm"  />   <br/>
   <input type="submit" class="button" value="JOIN!" name="join!"  />
</form>
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e458S/2/)

Finally I found one mistake, when password is typed, and before it I change the focus to another field, and returning back to password, the field clears. It's from 
`onclick="this.value=''";` if You want to handle event onclick just remove `this.value=''` because it works on onfocus, or just add the condition `if(this.value=='password')`, otherwise if use onclick event same as onfocus, better remove the onclick event handler, onfocus is enough.

Answer (score 3):

Keeping in mind the following:

- Password fields should be of `input type='password'`, which allows the browser to apply different security considerations (such as not allowing copying). In addition, touch devices may selectively offer to show/hide the password for usability purposes.
- Preferably, scripts should not be inline. Instead, prefer unobtrusive JavaScript which attaches itself to the appropriate elements.
- People use all sorts of input mechanisms.

I suggest the HTML `placeholder` attribute with feature detection to allow you to modify the display if `placeholder` is not supported.

Simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/fbw7j/3/

```
<input type="password" placeholder="enter a password">

// feature detection using the Modernizr library
if(!Modernizr.input.placeholder){
    // alter your markup
    $("input[type=password]").after("<span>Password</span>");
}
```

Comment: .. Ha.  I was going to offer the same library, but couldn't figure out how to make it work in IE9.

Answer (score 0):

look at http://jsfiddle.net/e458S/39/

```
<input type="text" class="button" value="PASSWORD-OK" onclick="this.value='';this.onclick='test';this.style.color='#000';" onfocus="if (this.value == 'PASSWORD-OK') {this.value = ''; this.type='password';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'PASSWORD-OK'; this.type='text';}" name="password"/>
```

but usage with placeholder is fine too.

```
<input type="password" placeholder="enter a password">
```